# How to call function from another file with requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, requirejs

I have two files - main, and events. I'm trying to call some function from one file to another.

So, this is how it looks:

**events**

```
require(['app/main'], function(call) {
    // click event respond test
    document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        if (target.hasClass === "call"){
            functionCall()();
        }
    });
});
```

**main**

```
define(["jquery"], function() {

    // Call
    var box = $('.box');
    return function functionCall(){
        box.addClass('visible');
    }
});
```

What is wrong, can anyboyd help?

Comment: I know you're trying to require a module in another file but what exactly are you trying to achieve when you call it?

Comment: call function from other file after click on some element - simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

main:

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {

    var main =  {
        functionCall: function(){
            $('.box').addClass('visible');
        }
    }

    return main;
});
```

events:

```
require(['jquery','app/main'], function($, main) {

    $('body').on('click', function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('call')){
            main.functionCall();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add this code where you need to make call to function:
`require('pathToModuleOrModuleName').functionYouWantToCall()`

But if you have module defined or required in the beggining (as 'main' in the events), then in place where call to function needed just add:

```
call.functionName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless my eyes deceive me the simplest change to make to your code would be to replace this:

```
functionCall()();
```

with this:

```
call();
```

since the function that the `main` module returns is imported as `call` in your `events` module, because that's how you name it in the callback passed to `define`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code has some basic problems

In the following code

```
define(["jquery"], function() {
```

Where are you referring the query inside the function definition.
I think you should first map the jquery defined into the function declaration like below

```
  define(["jquery"], function($) {
```

Secondly, what is the () doing after the calling function?

```
if (target.hasClass === "call"){
   functionCall()();
}
```

Remove the trailing () from that call. It should just be functionCall();

Comment: i have maped jquery in my main/config file, and that is the write mistake, my function is defined corectly... :)