# Calling a function from one controller that is wrapped in "require" in another controller

Tags: javascript, requirejs, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I want main.js to call makeAMap() from map.js, but makeAMap() is wrapped in a "require" statement that is really giving me a hard time, I have even tried making it global. At first the issue seemed to be just that the function was loading too late, but after trying the callbacks and the function wrapper I think it's a combined problem with timing and the "require". For now I've found a workaround, but I would rather main.js run the method.

I have tried callbacks, function wrappers, various global and window variables, and $.getScript. map.js is imported first in the html.
I found this similar post
 [How to call function from another file with requireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336898/how-to-call-function-from-another-file-with-requirejs) 
but it seems to be going to opposite direction and I don't think I can apply the solution. There is another similar question
[How do I call a function that is defined inside of require() outside of the require()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666868/how-do-i-call-a-function-that-is-defined-inside-of-require-outside-of-the-requ)
but the answer has more to do with the button/event and doesn't really help me.

```
//map.js
makeAMap = function (mapBasemap) {}; //a global function
loadTheMapController = function(){
  require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView"
    ], function (Map, MapView) {

    makeAMap = function(mapBasemap){ //overrides the global function
        var theMap = new Map({
            basemap: mapBasemap
        });
        return theMap;}
console.log(makeAMap); //displays the correct function after loadTheMapController is called
}//end loadTheMapController wrapper


//main.js
console.log(makeAMap); //displays the empty global function
loadTheMapController();
console.log(makeAMap); // still displaying empty global function


//even tried this
$.when(loadTheMapController()).then(console.log(makeAMap));
//returns the empty function like it wasn't overwritten
```

alternatively just to test that the global var is being overwritten

```
//map.js
 var makeAMap;
   $(document).ready(function () {
  require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView"
  ], function (Map, MapView) {

   makeAMap = function(mapBasemap){
        var theMap = new Map({
            basemap: mapBasemap
        });
        return theMap;
    }
      console.log(makeAMap); //returns the correct function
}//end of doc.ready
console.log(makeAMap); //returns undefined
```

I suppose I am having multiple problems here, the first of which is my global function is not being overwritten. Sorry for the layered question. What do you think?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Why are you trying to call `makeAMap()` from your main.js? There are a lot of scope issues with what you are trying to do. Its better to just let that function run inside of the `require` (which is the Dojo AMD module loader, not requirejs). If you really need access to any objects that are within the map logic (such as the `View` object) then store that in an object that is outside of the scope of the `require`.

Comment: My main.js reads my data.json, and performs several functions with it. The map.js's makeAMap() function also requires information from data.json, and I would like to just call it in the same block of code in main.js. The workaround I have is to put the data into a global variable and it runs in map.js, which I hear is bad design. 

Here is the github link if it's helpful
https://github.com/Rochelle-DRG/Cascade-StoryMap

Comment: Well, AFAIK, if we are using `RequireJS`, we better keep the design clean and use `RequireJS` for everything in order to avoid issues like the one you are facing now. You can even wrap you `loadTheMapController` inside a `Promise` and `resolve` it inside the `require`, then use it later, but it is also bad design.

Comment: it looks like you want to exec makeAMap() when document is ready. There is a function in RequireJS to do that. Just add "dojo/domReady!" at the end of the require's array : `require([..., "dojo/domReady!"], function (Map, MapView) {`

Comment: Castro Roy, when you say use RequireJS for everything, are you suggesting that I repeat the Require and import the esri classes in my main.js, or that instead of having a main.js at all importing data from .json and building html, I put all that code inside the Require in my map.js? That would make for a very long .js file.

Comment: LMokrane, my makeAMap() requires arguments that come from page.json and are already imported and used in main.js which builds my html elements including the div that the Map made will go into. Right now as a workaround map.js is calling makeAMap() when doc.ready using a global variable that main.js sets with page.json data. I think this may not be the best design and would like to find a smarter way.